# Why @EnableWs removed aop proxy from spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop

I am trying to add custom interceptor in my spring boot web service project. I follow [this](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-intercept-request-response-soap-messages/) example and created this config:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.List;

import org.aspect.PersistentAspect;
import org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointInterceptor;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WsConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        final MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/v1/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema schema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("country.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        String[] jaxbContext = new String[] { "io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service" };
        marshaller.setContextPaths(jaxbContext);
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        // aop not working
        interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), config()));
        // aop working
        // interceptors.add(new CustomValidatingInterceptor(schema(), null));
    }

    @Bean
    public AppConfig config() {
        return new AppConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentAspect persistentAspect() {
        PersistentAspect persistentAspect = new PersistentAspect();
        return persistentAspect;
    }

    @Bean
    public Object testAop() {
        System.out.println("is config aop proxy: " + AopUtils.isAopProxy(config()));

        return null;
    }
}
```

however when I am adding new interceptor in `addInterceptors` method I have problem with removed aop proxy in my config class. Any idea why ? Whole project is on [git](https://github.com/hudi1/aop-test).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the initialization sequence in Spring.  Technically, because there is a `BeanPostProcessor` for the WS Endpoint (`AnnotationActionEndpointMapping` in spring-ws), it will force the early initialization of any dependencies this needs - especially any `EndpointInterceptor` beans.

One way to counter this is to rearrange the BeanPostProcessor's, or even create one of your own, but usually its simpler to stay with the default configuration in Spring - to avoid similar surprises elsewhere in the initialization sequence.

Perhaps a simpler way to avoid the problem is to use an `ObjectFactory` in the `EndpointInterceptor` bean.  This will delay instantiating the `AppConfig` bean until it is referenced, by which time the Aop weaving will also have taken place.

```
@Component
public class CustomValidatingInterceptor extends PayloadValidatingInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectFactory<AppConfig> konfigurace;

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint)
            throws IOException, SAXException, TransformerException {
        System.out.println("is config aop proxy in interceptor: " +
                AopUtils.isAopProxy(konfigurace.getObject()));
        return super.handleRequest(messageContext, endpoint);
    }
```

Clearly, this then means the `CustomValidatingInterceptor` must be referenced from `WsConfig` as an injected (autowired) bean.

Thanks for the example - there's a fork [here](https://github.com/df789/aop-test) that uses the `ObjectFactory` technique.  This showed the `config` bean as an Aop proxy in all of `WsConfig.testAop()`, the `CountryEndpoint` and the `CustomValidatingInterceptor` when I sent a request in from SoapUI.

Comment: thx a lot works like a charm. Is this behavior somewhere documented ?

Comment: Hmmm, good question.  This knowledge came from a day like the one you're describing...  The best technique I know to see what's going on is to use a breakpoint when one of the beans is being initialized.  Look for the `PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors()` method a way back in the stack.  There's quite a bit going on in there, with `priorityOrderedPostProcessors`, `orderedPostProcessors` and `nonOrderedPostProcessors` being initialized.  I prefer to find a way to avoid my bean being initialized by any of those, as it will probably be too early.

Comment: yea I tried to debug with this method and saw my configuration is initialized sooner. I just did not see any reason why it is happening before aop and also dont know this objectFactory trick

Comment: I knew this would have been something related to load order, but since I don't work with spring, I knew it would be hard to provide an answer like this. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility to solve this issue. This relates to following Stack overflow question: [Spring WS interceptors with injected DAO's @Transactional not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214297/spring-ws-interceptors-with-injected-daos-transactional-not-working/56132662). In short the issue comes from the fact that the method

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
```

gets called before Spring dependency injection has time to register Spring AOP beans. In my case it was @Transactional that was ignored by Spring-WS but it could be anything.

Fortunately for us Spring-WS uses mutable collections instead of immutable. When the `addInterceptors()` method 
gets called, we can just save the collection and thus we have a reference to the same collection instance that is used by Spring-WS. Later on you can initialize your interceptor bean properly and add it to the collection.

You also have to get around the fact that if you use `@Autowired` the bean gets prepared before the annotations can take place. Thus you have to create it manually by calling `ApplicationContext.getBean()` method.

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
// The magic is to implement both ApplicationContextAware 
// that injects the applicationContext for us 
// and BeanPostProcessor that gives us postProcessBeforeInitialization() 
// where we initialize our interceptor correctly 
// and add it to the collection
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware, BeanPostProcessor {

    // This is the interceptor that uses dependencies with @Transactional annotation.
    // It will not work with @Autowired
    private MyInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies myInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies;
    // Fortunately Spring WS uses mutable collections so we can fill 
    // this list later on as long as we just initialize it with  
    private List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors;
    // This is our application context where all the beans are defined
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        // save application context for later use
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }

    @Nullable
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        // This method gets called multiple times so initialize interceptor just once
        if(myInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies == null){
            myInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies = context.getBean(MyInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies.class);
            interceptors.add(myInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies);
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        // Save the list of interceptors so we can modify it later on
        this.interceptors = interceptors; 
        if (myInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies == null) {
            System.out.println("myInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies was null like we expected");
        } else {
            interceptors.add(myInterceptorThatHasTransactionalDependencies);
        }
    }
}
```

Just to let you know that I am not Spring bean lifecycle expert, so there might be a better place to situate the interceptor initialization than `postProcessBeforeInitialization()`. That said, this works for me.